# What is the purpose of UVVM's t_void type?

Tags: vhdl

In the [`types_pkg`](https://github.com/UVVM/UVVM/blob/master/uvvm_util/src/types_pkg.vhd#L34) package of UVVM's `uvvm_util` library, the type `t_void` is defined as an enumeration type with a single literal:

```
type t_void is (VOID);
```

This type is used throughout the library to define procedures that don't take a useful parameter:

```
procedure whatever (constant dummy: in t_void) is
begin
    -- dummy is not used
end;
```

When invoking such a procedure, one must pass `VOID`:

```
whatever (VOID);
```

The same procedure could also have been written as:

```
procedure whatever is
begin
    -- No dummy here
end;
```

So what is the purpose of the `t_void` type and the `dummy` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just used to enhance the readability of the code from the user perspective. For instance, if `void` argument is not there in the procedure, you would invoke the procedure in codes as:

```
whatever ;
```

As a user seeing this statement, it **NEVER** gives assurance to you that this procedure doesn't take in any arguments. You would then have to look up at the package and trace the procedure definition to confirm what are the arguments. It may well be taking an argument and using it inside, which is defaulted in the procedure, like:

```
procedure whatever (variable temp : in std_logic := '0') is
begin
   ...
end procedure ;
```

It is still fine to invoke the above procedure as:

```
  whatever        ;    --  no/implicit argument
  whatever (flag) ;    -- 'flag' is a variable (explicit argument)
```

By using `VOID` argument in the procedure `whatever`, and invoking it as `whatever (VOID)`,
it is being made clear to the user that `whatever` is a procedure that **NEVER** takes in any argument, default or explicit.

We have similar concept in *C* language standards as well.

Comment: I find this specious reasoning. See [Bitvis UVVM VHDL Verification Component Framework](https://wiki.uib.no/ift/index.php/Bitvis_UVVM_VHDL_Verification_Component_Framework#Implement_first_tests), the code example comment explaining:  `--dummy variable is included only to allow calling the procedure with parenthesis for readability`. Further the need for parentheses for readability is dubious. A procedure call is a statement and can't be mistaken for anything else in VHDL's syntax.

Comment: Might be the coding conventions followed by who ever is the author of the code.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this anwer, because the same would apply to functions _with_ parameters as well: if I see `whatever ('0');`, I also can't be sure that this procedure doesn't take any _further_ arguments. I don't see why the fact that there are no optional parameters should be highlighted for procedures with zero mandatory parameters, but not for others.

Comment: The explanation cited by @user8352's seems _slightly_ more plausible: that the parentheses make it clearer that a procedure is being called (cf. C, where we'd write `foo ();` rather than `foo;`). Still, (a) that wouldn't apply to procedure calls where all parameters are defaulted (e. g. `print_hierarchical_log;`), (b) as @user8352 points out (and contrary to what is claimed on the cited page), there is no ambiguity here, and (c) arguably, the VOID argument actually _hurts_ readability by adding clutter (but that may be a matter of personal preference).

Comment: In C, a non void argument list can take in infinite arguments during invoking regardless of how the function is defined. So programmers use void argument to assert that there are no arguments allowed while calling this function.  I guess the author is trying to bring similar convention here. However VHDL being strictly typed doesn't any allow that flexibility in argument list while invoking a function, like in C. So, the author of the library need not use void at all here.